# MySQL Gem for Ruby On Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched everywhere and no ones solutions solve my problem. I have built rails apps using SQLite but not MySQL. For this particular project, I need MySQL. When I attempt to boot the server I get an error, so I attempt to install the gems for MySQL and get another error. Does anyone have any insight? Thank you!

```
    rails server
    Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

    sudo gem install mysql2
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


    Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: It looks like you are running OSX... which version?  Have you installed the development tools (Xcode) for your version of OSX?

Comment: How did you install mysql on your os x machine?

Comment: OS X should already have MySQL installed... but you can also download binaries from the [MySQL website](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

Comment: Running 10.6.6. I'm trying to use MAMP as MySQL server, but I believe I have MySQL installed directly from the binary.

Comment: reinstalled server via binary but now get this:

`dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap`

Comment: this might help: http://www.gregbenedict.com/2009/08/29/fixing-ruby-gems-mysql-and-passenger-phusion-on-snow-leopard-10-6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem.  You need to install the mysql gem with native extensions.

The line you're probably looking for is this:

```
$ ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 --version '~> 0.2.7' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Full write up on getting it going here: http://softwaregravy.com/mysql-on-os-x-rails-3-0-7/