# Lazy symbol binding failed when creating ruby db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am trying to install ruby on rails, and everything is installed now so far, but when I try to create a database with `rake db:create`, I get a weird error:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
>     Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
>     Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>
> Trace/BPT trap: 5

I am working on osx mountain lion latest update. Does anyone have the right solution for me?

Answer (score 4):

You might try this.

```
sudo gem install mysql2 — –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Be sure to modify the mysql config path with the location for yours.

You can determine this with the following command.

```
locate mysql_config
```

Leverage the path given with the command above.

Comment: where should the mysql_config path go? do i have to use the link to my sql that I already downloaded from the sql website (mysql-5.5.29-osx10.6-x86) or the one installed with the gem?

Comment: When I run the above command I get ERROR:  could not find gem — locally or in a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config locally or in a repository

Comment: when I run locate mysql_config I get the next message: WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist. ehm but I already got a mysql server installed from the mysql website that I usually use?

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682386/mysql-gem-for-ruby-on-rails 
Note the comments in the question that list your exact error.

Comment: Seen that post already but it didn't seem to work.. I am trying to update the db with: sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb and try if locate works after that.. pff why is rails such a pain in the *** :(

Comment: However much pain I've had setting up Rails over the years is nothing compared to the pain avoided while using it.

Comment: After doing al this suggestions I still keep getting the error.. Hopefully someone can provide the correct answer.. off

Comment: one thing to note in the above code, it is `sudo gem install myslq2` "dash dash space dash dash" etc. it took ages for me to figure this out mysql. that is why you are getting "ERROR: could not find gem -- locally"

Answer (score 4):

The messge is telling that you have linked wrong version 32 vs. 64

On OSX you can see all versions on mysql installed

```
cd /usr/local/
```

and find right config in /usr/local/mysql-xxxx/bin/mysql_config

In my case it was:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
sudo gem install mysql2 -- 
--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.27-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
```

As discussed here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1440086

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous questions about this and at least as many answers that work some of the time but not others.  After trying most of them I noticed that the gem was 64bit and the mysql installation was 32bit.

To fix it:

- install the 64 bit mysql
- set up the symbolic links in /usr/local to point to the 64 bit version
- set the PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in your profile to include the correct versions
- uninstall the mysql2 gem
- install the mysql2 gem
- ruby now plays nicely with mysql!

I haven't included the exact code as this tends to vary with your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time with this one.. I tried all of the answers above, so I can't really pinpoint what combination resulted in the fix. I already had mysql installed and had reinstalled from mysql's website. It finally started working after I followed the bellow.

This is on Mavericks using rails 4 and brew is installed

```
brew install mysql
```

I'm not recommending this process .. Just noting that it worked for me after hours of frustration.

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

sudo gem uninstall mysql
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql
gem install mysql2
```

Comment: this worked for me as well running ruby 2.3, mysql56 installed via homebrew

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 64 bit MySql server. Don't forget to re-install mysql gem.

Answer (score 0):

I had two versions of mysql installed (32 & 64 bit) for some reason.

Make sure your $MYSQL environmental variable (most likely found in ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile) is pointing at the 64 bit version.

Also make sure you point towards the correct the mysql install when your installing the gem as the other answers have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. mysql2 version was 0.4.9, downgraded it to 0.4.5 and problem solved