# OSX dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, bash, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed mysql (5.6.27), the newest mysql version at this time(5.7..).

I have mysql2 gem installed with version - 0.3.14

When i try to run `rake db:create` i get error message:

```
Karliss-Air:gostyling myuser$ rake db:create
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

BUT the wierd thing is when i run `nm -gU` it shows that the dylib is there:

```
Karliss-Air:gostyling myuser$ nm -gU /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib | grep _mysql_get_client_info
0000000000002ff5 T _mysql_get_client_info
Karliss-Air:gostyling myuser$
```

I have tryed to define mysql path when instsalling the gem

```
gem pristine mysql2 -v '0.3.14' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27 -–with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27/bin/mysql_config
```

It doesnt help.

I would really appriciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by reinstalling my macbook. The problem, i think, was that i installed mysql5.7 first, then tryed to use mysql56. After reinstall i installed mysql56 straight away and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using rvm/without rvm(just use sudo) then please use the following command which solve the issues.

```
rvmsudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-opt-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib
```

else try,uninstalling mysql2 gem and then installing gem with sudo would solve it sometimes.

```
sudo gem uninstall mysql2

sudo gem install mysql2
```

or look into this: [Lazy symbol binding failed when creating ruby db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293118/lazy-symbol-binding-failed-when-creating-ruby-db)

Comment: i dont think its the right approach but uninstalling and installing it few times worked for me in past

Comment: uninstalling and installing the gem with `sudo` worked for me